# Messed Up Characters In Javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, cjk

So, I have a few files sent to me which contain a bunch of stuff like this

```
var time=0;//ÓÎÏ·Ê±¼ä
```

Obviously, the comment corresponds to something, which I'd like to read, but it's messed up and I don't know why.

1) How do I read this

2) How do I avoid it

Comment: Where are you receiving this from? It looks like the server is not specifying the encoding correctly.

Comment: Its is probably some asian language like chinese. You can't read because your system don't have the "files for East Asian languages" installed.

Answer (score 2):

Find out which character encoding the file is saved in, then instruct your editor to open the file using that encoding.

If you're on a GNU/Linux box, you can get a good guess at the encoding using this command:

```
file -i file.js
```

Here's a simple page I hacked up for those who don't have access to the `file` command: http://lajm.eu/encoding/